# Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE + Hibernate 5.2.0.Final - GeneratedValue on mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

When i try to add new row to table with AUTO Id i got Error, but when i insert ID and dont use "@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)" it works fine

My Error:

```
יול 03, 2016 4:41:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [searcher] in context with path [/Searcher] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'searcherdb.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.executeQuery(TableStructure.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.access$300(TableStructure.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:412)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:667)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:659)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:654)
    at com.searcher.dao.EcommerceImp.add(EcommerceImp.java:29)
    at com.searcher.service.EcommerceServiceImp.add(EcommerceServiceImp.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.searcher.controller.MainSearcherController.helloWorld(MainSearcherController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It looks like that hibernate wants "hibernate_sequence" table but it isnt auto create...

My EcommerceRntity:

```
package com.searcher.entity;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ecommerce")
public class EcommerceEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int Id;

    @Column
    private String Name;

    @Column
    private String Path;

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return Path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.Path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Id = " + Id + ", Name = " + Name + ", Path = " + Path;
    }

}
```

My MainCollector:

```
package com.searcher.controller;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity;
import com.searcher.service.EcommerceService;
import com.searcher.service.EcommerceServiceImp;

@Controller
public class MainSearcherController {

    @Autowired
    private EcommerceService ecommerceService;

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is coming from MainSearcherController.java **********</div><br><br>";
        String strEndList = "";

        try {
            //ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("searcher-servlet.xml");
            //EcommerceDAO ecommerceDAO = context.getBean(EcommerceDAO.class);

            //EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory");
            //EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();


            // Creating ImageService object
            EcommerceEntity ecommerceEntity = new EcommerceEntity();

            //ecommerceEntity.setId(4564564);
            ecommerceEntity.setName("Ebay");
            ecommerceEntity.setPath("www.ebay.com");

            this.ecommerceService.add(ecommerceEntity);


            //strEndList = "<br/><br/>" + ecommerceService.getAllEcommerce().toString() + "<br/><br/>";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }


        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message + strEndList);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Searcher</groupId>
    <artifactId>Searcher</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <!-- Build -->
    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

searcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Searcher-Servlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- DataSource -->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SearcherDB" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>



    <!-- Hibernate 5 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.ImageEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.ProductEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.ProductRequestEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.RequestEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.SellerEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.UserEntity</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- eCommerce -->
    <beans:bean id="ecommerceDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.EcommerceImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="ecommerceService" class="com.searcher.service.EcommerceServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="ecommerceDAO" ref="ecommerceDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Image -->
    <beans:bean id="imageDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.ImageImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="imageService" class="com.searcher.service.ImageServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="imageDAO" ref="imageDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Product -->
    <beans:bean id="productDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.ProductImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="productService" class="com.searcher.service.ProductServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="productDAO" ref="productDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- ProductRequest -->
    <beans:bean id="productRequestDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.ProductRequestImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="productRequestService"
        class="com.searcher.service.ProductRequestServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="productRequestDAO" ref="productRequestDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Request -->
    <beans:bean id="requestDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.RequestImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="requestService" class="com.searcher.service.RequestServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="requestDAO" ref="requestDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Seller -->
    <beans:bean id="sellerDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.SellerImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="sellerService" class="com.searcher.service.SellerServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="sellerDAO" ref="sellerDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- User -->
    <beans:bean id="userDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.UserImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.searcher.service.UserServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.searcher." />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: If this is a code from tutorial you should include a link, and tell us what did you do with the code to have a problem.

Comment: Can you provide your hibernate configuration ?

Comment: The target table doesn't exist. **If you want it to be auto-created**, then you can add property `<beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</beans:prop>` inside the tag `<beans:property name="hibernateProperties">`. This allows to create a database required when the SessionFactory is created. This is useful for tests. However, **DO NOT use it with your production database which contains real data.**

Comment: Check hibernate configuration guide to know how to use different value of property: [hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-misc-properties)

Comment: Ok but if i want it to Production i need to generate the ID separately? or is there another way to so it?

Comment: @RomanC, can you help that ? I don't have enough experience to answer this question.

Comment: I think the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is for database management and `@GeneratedValue` is for entity's ID management. They're not the same. In production database, you shouldn't set the `hbm2ddl.auto` to `create`, but you can still use the `@GeneratedValue`.

Comment: @MincongHuang Yes i think you right, mabye after i checked all the Tables and when it working perfect in Debug mode i remove the AUTO propery and uplode to production. thank you very much to your help!

Comment: It's my pleasure. Happy coding and hope you get through these issues. Good luck ;)

Comment: @MincongHuang In production you should comment out `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`.

Comment: @RomanC Thank you, i will remove it when uploading to production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As outlined in comments, you can use the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` configuration setting to control how Hibernate will bootstrap your SessionFactory and manage your schema.  You can find more information on the various options for this setting [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl); however, it is recommended that you typically not use this option in a production environment.

The message regarding `hibernate_sequences` table comes from a change in default behavior between Hibernate 4.x and 5.x releases.

In the 4.x release stream, the `@GeneratedValue` annotation would default to using data types such as `AUTO_INCREMENT` on MySQL or `IDENTITY` on SQL Server to name a few.  In other words, the row's primary key was handled by the database natively in conjunction with the column data type used.

In the 5.x release stream, the default behavior changed due to a new set of identifier generator mappings that were introduced in 4.3.x.  The `AUTO` behavior now uses these new id generator mappings instead which rely on the `hibernate_sequences` table.

If you want the 4.x behavior while using Hibernate 5.x, you can either set the configuration `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false` or you can simply change the annotation on the class to be specific, e.g. `@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )`.

Comment: I'm surprised, Hibernate team mostly  recommended to use a new generator up from version 4 for new applications.

Comment: I have no experience of it but if you mean version 5.ס should be used in IDENTITY So I use it. Thank you for the answer

Comment: @RomanC That is correct, it is recommended to use the new generators instead, particularly for new applications.

Comment: @Guyb No what @RomanC was saying is that it is recommended that you take advantage of the default behavior, e.g. use `hibernate_sequences` in conjunction with the `@GeneratedValue` auto-detect behavior without changing your configuration settings or annotations as I suggested if you wanted old behavior.

Comment: @Naros Then you should use  `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true`, and do you mean Hibernate 5 has set it  to true by default?

Comment: @RomanC Yes. In Hibernate 4, `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` was disabled by default but in Hibernate 5 it is now enabled by default since it is the recommended strategy moving forward.

Comment: @Naros ok but if i want to use the most updated version i dont need to right AUTO or IDENTITY?

Comment: @Guyb If you want to simply use `@GeneratedValue` with Hibernate 5 and do nothing, you need to have the table `hibernate_sequences` created.

Comment: @Naros good and after it all works I remove the auto generate of the hibernate_sequence? and it can be good for production?

Comment: @Guyb You should probably read the documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators).  That table will be needed in `ALL` your environments.  How you plan to transport that table definition through your enterprise is entirely up to you.  It is simply recommended not to use the schema generation tool on a production database is all.

Comment: @Naros That's right, you should write DDL by hand and not rely on Hibernate :)